# Pass extra parameters to custom sort function in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

This is my code

```
<a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'productname'; reverse=false">Productname</a>
<a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'productprice'; reverse=false">Productprice</a>
```

Iteration

```
 <div ng-repeat="sale in sales | orderBy:customSort">
```

Customsort function

```
$scope.customSort = function(sale) {


 };
```

Currently in the customSort function I get all the sale data but I also want to pass the predicate value to the function so that it can sort accordingly(sort by name if name is clicked, sort by price if price predicate is clicked.)

How can I pass the predicate value to the customSort function?Can any one please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: use a colon in markup to delimit arguments [see filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: @charlietfl this should be an answer

Comment: @charlietfl [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) appears to just take an expression

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh can also use custom filter function without `orderBy` , not 100% clear what intent is here because mixing several issues

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could call your custom sort with the predicate and return a closure being your original function, now your function has access to predicate:

```
<div ng-repeat="sale in sales | orderBy:customSort(predicate)">

$scope.customSort = function(predicate) {
    return function(sale) {


    };
};
```

Comment: This solved my problem for passing $viewValue into the return function, however I wonder how performant something like this is.  I note that on every keystroke, the custom sort 'factory' let's just call it, gets called.

https://gist.github.com/jusopi/283887919b87cba5edb6

Comment: @jusopi if it's only called on every keystroke i think it's unlikely to have any noticeable impact. if it was called on each iteration of the sort then there could be troubles, but that shouldn't happen